# append specific amount of empty rows to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append a specific amount of empty rows to that  df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cow': [2, 4, 8],
                  'shark': [2, 0, 0],
                  'pudle': [10, 2, 1]})
```

with `df = df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)` I append one empty row, how can I append x amount of rows ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to achieve this goal.

```
df.reindex(list(range(0, 10))).reset_index(drop=True)

   cow  shark  pudle
0  2.0    2.0   10.0
1  4.0    0.0    2.0
2  8.0    0.0    1.0
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
4  NaN    NaN    NaN
5  NaN    NaN    NaN
6  NaN    NaN    NaN
7  NaN    NaN    NaN
8  NaN    NaN    NaN
9  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

The arguments you provide to `df.reindex` is going to be the *total* number of rows the new DataFrame has. So if your DataFrame has 3 objects, providing a list that caps out at 10 will add 7 new rows.

Comment: This converts int64 columns to float64, which is undesirable.

Comment: @JoshuaChia it worked for OP hence it was marked as resolved so your comment is not exactly truthful.

Comment: desirable enough for OP but not desireable enough in general, to be truthful, though OP's original answer appending one row has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too pandas savvy, but if you can already add one empty row, why not just try writing a for loop and appending x times?

```
for i in range(x):
    df = df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `reindex`

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.tolist()+[df.index.max()+1]*5)#reset_index(drop=True)
Out[93]: 
   cow  shark  pudle
0  2.0    2.0   10.0
1  4.0    0.0    2.0
2  8.0    0.0    1.0
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
3  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: index is a little borked, might want to throw a `reset_index` in there

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cow': [2, 4, 8],
                  'shark': [2, 0, 0],
                  'pudle': [10, 2, 1]})

n = 10
df = df.append([[] for _ in range(n)], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    cow  shark  pudle
0   2.0    2.0   10.0
1   4.0    0.0    2.0
2   8.0    0.0    1.0
3   NaN    NaN    NaN
4   NaN    NaN    NaN
5   NaN    NaN    NaN
6   NaN    NaN    NaN
7   NaN    NaN    NaN
8   NaN    NaN    NaN
9   NaN    NaN    NaN
10  NaN    NaN    NaN
11  NaN    NaN    NaN
12  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dataframe of the appropriate size and append it:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * df.shape[1]] * n,columns=df.columns), 
               ignore_index = True)
```